# sql multiple tables replace results from table

Tags: sql-server, select, union

I have a **HUGE** MSSQL database (nearly 120 gigs).  That database contains 1371 tables.  Only 3 of those tables are ones that I am concerned with for the moment.

Tables that I will be working with:

1. Messages
2. MessageUser
3. User

Fields in the table "Messages" that I will be working with:

- Subject
- Body
- FromMessageUserID
- PriorityID

***Messages.FromMessageuserID*** matches ***MessageUser.MessageUserID***

Fields in the table "MessageUser" that I will be working with:

- MessageUserID
- UserID

  ***MessageUser.UserID*** matches ***User.UserID***

Fields in the table "Users" that I will be working with:

- UserID
- Username

Right now I can run a query of:
SELECT     Subject, Body, FromMessageUserID, PriorityID
FROM         Messages

And get the results that are displayed as such:

Subject     Body        FromMessageUserID   PriorityID

Sub1        Body1       1001            1

Sub2        Body2       1002            3

Sub3        Body3       1001            2

So I want to see who sent the message with "Sub3" as the subject.

I start by looking into the MessageUser table, I can see that MessageUserID of 1001 has a UserID of 10.

I then go to the Users table, and I can see that the UserID of 10 has the Username of "JohnDoe".

Is there any way for me to run a query, and have the returned results resemble this:

Subject     Body        FromMessageUserID   PriorityID

Sub1        Body1       JohnDoe         1

Sub2        Body2       JaneDoe         3

Sub3        Body3       JohnDoe         2

I am not concerned with the PriorityID, as I know what the values (4 in total) are.

I am sure the proper way to go about this is with a JOIN or UNION, however I have never used them and every attempt I have made over the past few hours has failed.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
SELECT m.Subject, m.Body, u.UserName,m.PriorityID FROM Messages m
inner join MessageUser mu on mu.MessageUserId = m.FromMessageUserID
inner join users u on mu.UserID = u.UserID
```